# How to unlock gnome-keyring using command line

Tags: command-line, kde, kubuntu, mysql-workbench, gnome-keyring

My purpose is simply getting GnomeKeyring to prompt for a password. As some  people may want to know why, MySQL Workbench only uses GnomeKeyring for password protection for some reason and doesn't unlock it before connecting. It asks for the already stored password again then unlocks the keyring to save it over it. From then on, it lets you use the keyring as intended.

Amazingly enough, on top of this abomination, Google, almost exclusively assumes you are using gnome and want to get rid of the password prompt at autologin whenever you type gnome keyring and password prompt in the search (e.g [like this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=911&ei=6FE4XcHME4ey6QTenqXwBg&q=how+to+get+gnome+keyring+to+prompt+for+password&oq=how+to+get+gnome+keyring+to+prompt+for+password&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i21.13279.32454..32609...0.0..0.355.6377.1j7j4j13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i160.Wcv2RuISXo8&ved=0ahUKEwjB4Lz-yc3jAhUHWZoKHV5PCW4Q4dUDCAo&uact=5),[or this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=911&ei=rWE4Xf_zLLWU1fAPtZCzoA0&q=how+to+prompt+unlock+keyring+dialog&oq=how+to+prompt+unlock+keyring+dialog&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30.333136.352327..353658...4.0..0.172.4528.3j36......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0j0i67j0i203j0i20i263j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j33i160j33i21.hAwLC_1qhHk&ved=0ahUKEwi__tSD2c3jAhU1ShUIHTXIDNQ4FBDh1QMICg&uact=5) ). I have run out of ways to try to tell google what I want without it assuming I need the most popular answer, so here I am.

I am using:
Kubuntu 19.04
KDE Plasma 5.15.4

I simply need to know what command to run in `.profile` so that the password prompt window appears. This is because I started to think asking it to happen on MySQL Workbench start is too much to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I managed to find is trying to access a key. I found `gkeyring` the easiest to work with ([Here's the package](https://github.com/kparal/gkeyring)). After installing the package, all that is needed to be done is to run `gkeyring --all` before running MySQL Workbench.

The best way to implement was adding `gkeyring --all &&` before the command that starts MySQL Workbench that I always use.

Comment: You shouldn't use gkeyring anymore as it is not maintained anymore.

Comment: i don't. mysql-workbench does